# Is there any way to return SETOF without table name in Hasura graphql custom sql function

Tags: postgresql, graphql, hasura

I have created custom sql function in hasura and tracked it.
But need to write table name  in "`RETURNS SETOF <table-name>`" (Refer: https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/schema/custom-functions.html).
Here I cannot create new table having schema same as the function is returning columns.
I have lots of function to create so that I want a solution where I can create a function having return SETOF without table name.

Even in hasura function can't returns virtual table (i.e. `RETURNS Table(column1 text, column2 text, column3 text)` )

I tried "create type" and use it as

```
CREATE TYPE temp_type AS
(column1 text, column2 text, column3 text
);
```

But didn't work and giving following error:

"the function "my_function" cannot be tracked because the function does not return a SETOF table"

Any solution on this?

Here is my function

```
CREATE  FUNCTION my_function(fromDate text, toDate text)
RETURNS  SETOF  <table-name>  AS $$

// My function logic here 
// which returns column1, column2, column3

$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  hasura mentioned in their documentation "Return type: MUST be SETOF <table-name>" So we can't use ` setof <type-name> `

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I dont want to create extra tables/view as I have to write number of functions. And we can't use virtual table i.e. RETURNS SETOF Table(....)

Comment: @JimJones Hasuar already mentioned that "Return type: MUST be SETOF <table-name>"  Refer : https://docs.hasura.io/1.0/graphql/manual/schema/custom-functions.html    So we can't use it

Comment: how to overcome this issue?

Comment: @IamMashed Create a new dummy table to match the return type, and use that.